# Pandas: Splitting a Graph into many sub graphs while maintaining scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have a bar graph of 150 values.
The code is : 
    rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
    plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)

```
reso_names = [x[0] for x in resolution3]
reso_values = [x[1] for x in resolution3]

plt.bar(range(len(reso_values[0:20])), reso_values[0:20], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(reso_names[0:20])), list(reso_names[0:20]), rotation='vertical')

plt.margins(0.075)
plt.xlabel('Resolution Category Tier 3')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.title('Resolution Category Tier 3 Volume', {'family' : 'Arial Black',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22})

plt.savefig('Reso3.pdf', format='pdf')
plt.show()
```

Since I want to break it down into sub-graphs of 20 each to maintain readability I'm using the [0:20] at the reso_names and reso_values (both lists.

However the problem is that scale cannot be maintained, each sub-graphs have very different scales and that is a problem in terms of consistency not being maintained. How can I set a scale that can be maintained across all the graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `sharey=True` to keep the y-scale same in all subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)
# do simple plot here, replace barplot yourself
axes[0].plot(x)
axes[1].plot(y)
```

[image]

Or if you prefer to plot them separately, you can manually configure `ax.set_ylim()`.

Comment: Where do I put the command in my code ? I'm not using the plot command.